# Flowgear running old workflow version

Tags: application-integration, flowgear

I have a workflow that queries table and when there is available data it calls another workflow and retrieves the relevant data and then pushes it to a  web service. This is supposed run every 2 minutes.

Previously I had some test data in my variable bar, but I have long since removed it. Yet that data is getting pushed to the webservice constantly.

Why is the workflow still using the old test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flowgear caches sub-workflows on first encounter when they execute from a parent workflow. If you've modified a sub-workflow and re-saved it, that change won't take effect in the calling workflow until you restart it.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. I restarted and that sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to auto-start workflows is to restart the workflow after every workflow change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh the subworkflow's properties? To do this, right-click on the Workflow node, and click *refresh properties*